# Using python how to grep records in a huge reords file with millions of data

Tags: python

Using python what is the fastest way to grep a list of 100000 records in another million of records in a file in Linux.

Let's say these are my sample records :

```
5,DAMAGED,2,500,rabiou,XOFyu,20160227T12:10:16+0100,20201231T23:59:59+0100,,vsuser,,990825958226,9167447676,,,31001,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,C

0,,2,500,rabiou,XOFyu,20160227T12:10:16+0100,20201231T23:59:59+0100,20160227T12:10:16+0100,,vsuser,990825958226,9167447676,,,31001,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,H

5,DAMAGED,2,500,rabiou,XOFyu,20160227T12:10:16+0100,20201231T23:59:59+0100,20160307T21:17:42+0100,,vsuser,990825958226,9167447676,,,31001,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,H
```

So if i grep 990825958226 i need the last occurrence of the value and the combination should be the starting letter "5" which is common and ending letter "H" and letter "DAMAGED"

Kindly guide me to write a python for searching individual records if these three combination exists and to get the last occurrence line of each record.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post what you have so far in terms of sample code and let us know what isn’t working.

Comment: If you have "tons" of data try using [PySpark](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html)

Comment: I am new to the python scripting , so haven't tried . 

Previously i tried with some basic shell scripts which was taking more time.

Comment: Is your problem that you can't make it work, or you can't make it work fast enough, or you can't make it work reliably, or...?

Comment: I cant make it work faster :(